# Formatting console Output

Tags: python, text-formatting, console-output

I'm having trouble making python print out texts properly aligned. I have tried everything I knew, but still the same result and it's very annoying!.

Here is what I'm getting in the console 
[image]

Here is the Code I have.

```
print " FileName\t\t\t\t\tStatus\t\tBinary Type\n"  

for files in PASS:
    log = subprocess.check_output(['dumpbin','/HEADERS',files])
    if arch64 in log:
        print" %s \t\t\t\tPASSED\t\t 64-bit \t\t  " %files 
    elif arch32 in log:
        print" %s \t\t\t\tPASSED\t\t 32-bit \t\t  " %files
print"\n"   
for files in FAILED:

    print" %s \t\t\t\t  FAILED \t\t        " %files

print "\n\n
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `%45s` to make a right justified field that is 45 characters long. And use `%-45s` to make a left justified string. Also consider extracting your line printing into a function - that way you'll be able to change it easily in one place. Like this:

```
# fake setup 
PASS = ["foo.exe", "bar.exe", "really_long_filename.exe"]
FAILED = ["failed.exe"]
types = ["32-bit", "64-bit", "64-bit"]
arch64 = '64'
arch32 = '32'

# your code
def print_row(filename, status, file_type):
    print " %-45s %-15s %15s" % (filename, status, file_type)

print_row('FileName', 'Status', 'Binary Type')

for files in PASS:
    log = types.pop()
    if arch64 in log:
        print_row(files, 'PASSED', '64-bit')
    elif arch32 in log:
        print_row(files, 'PASSED', '32-bit')
print"\n"   

for files in FAILED:
        print_row(files, 'FAILED', '')

print "\n\n"
```

Comment: Thank you,  this works great :), can I ask you why did you use `type` as one of the function args?

Comment: erm ... should have been binary_type or something ... type is a bad choice of name as it's already a function in python ... it'll still work but not a good style ... so i've fixed it up above :)

Comment: Or [`str.ljust`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) for short

Answer (score 5):

In place of the tabs, it's better to use string formatting directives where it's possible to specify the exact number of spaces and to reserve for output.

For instance

```
print '>>%20s<<' %('some string')
>>         some string<<
```

will reserve 20 spaces and *right*-align this string for display. You can *left*-justify it by using `%-20s`

```
print '>>%-20s<<' %('some string')
>>some string         <<
```

Numbers can be specified using `d` for integers and `f` for float values. E.g.,

```
 print '%03d %5.2f' %(5, 22/7.0)
 005  3.14
```

In this example I reserved 3 zero-padded spaces for an integer value, and 5 spaces for a float (2 for values after the decimal space). You can control alignemnt here too with `-`. There are many other options to format output, see the suggested links below for more details.

Note that the use of the `.format()` function is encouraged. See SO my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10837046/1209279) about how to use `.format()`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099782/python-numbers-formatting/11099798#11099798) may also help.

While `.format` may seem very verbose, it does offer a great deal of flexibility and one of my favorite features is the ability to easily print commas in large numbers for readability.

See [Python docs on String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for much more details to help you line up your output just exactly the way you'd like it.

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify it a lot if you use string formatting with [padding](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), for eg.

```
>>> '%20s' % 'test'
'                test'
>>> '%-20s' % 'test'
'test                '
```

Answer (score 2):

i suggest using ljust with them some thing like

```
print files.ljust(20) + 'Passed'.ljust(5) + '64-bit'
```

instead of this :

```
print" %s \t\t\t\tPASSED\t\t 64-bit \t\t  " %files
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a third party module for formatting the output to the console.

i.e.:
[texttable](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=texttable&%3aaction=display)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering how to do this in python 3:

You can do this terminal alignment using f-strings

```py
# assigning list values to the variables
names = ['Raj', 'Shivam', 'Shreeya', 'Kartik']
marks = [7, 9, 8, 5]
div = ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B']
id = [21, 52, 27, 38]
  
# printing Aligned Header
print(f"{'Name' : <10}{'Marks' : ^10}{'Division' : ^10}{'ID' : >5}")
  
# printing values of variables in Aligned manner
for i in range(0, 4):
    print(f"{names[i] : <10}{marks[i] : ^10}{div[i] : ^10}{id[i] : >5}")
```

Output:

```
Name        Marks    Division    ID
Raj           7         A        21
Shivam        9         A        52
Shreeya       8         C        27
Kartik        5         B        38
```

credit: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-alignment-in-python-f-string/