# In Python, display output of SQL query as a table, just like it does in SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

this seems like a basic function, but I'm new to Python so maybe I'm not googling this correctly.

In Microsoft SQL Server, when you have a statement like

```
SELECT top 100 * FROM dbo.Patient_eligibility
```

you get a result like

```
 Patient_ID | Patient_Name | Patient_Eligibility

     67456  | Smith, John  | Eligible
     ...         
     etc.
```

Etc.

I am running a connection to SQL through Python as such, and would like the output to look exactly the same as in SQL. Specifically - with column names and all the data rows specified in the SQL query. It doesn't have to appear in the console or the log, I just need a way to access it to see what's in it.

Here is my current code attempts:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT top 100 * FROM [dbo].[PATIENT_ELIGIBILITY]"
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()

#Query1
for row in data :
    print (row[1])

#Query2
print (data)

#Query3
data
```

My understanding is that somehow the results of PATIENT_ELIGIBILITY are stored in the variable data. Query 1, 2, and 3 represent methods of accessing that data that I've googled for - again seems like basic stuff.

The results of #Query1 give me the list of the first column, without a column name in the console. In the variable explorer, 'data' appears as type List. When I open it up, it just says 'Row object of pyodbc module' 100 times, one for each row. Not what I'm looking for. Again, I'm looking for the same kind of view output I would get if I ran it in Microsoft SQL Server.

Running #Query2 gets me a little closer to this end. The results appear like a .csv file - unreadable, but it's all there, in the console.

Running #Query3, just the 'data' variable, gets me the closest result but with no column names. How can I bring in the column names?

More directly, how do i get 'data' to appear as a clean table with column names somewhere? Since this appears a basic SQL function, could you direct me to a SQL-friendly library to use instead?

Also note that neither of the Queries required me to know the column names or widths. My entire method here is attempting to eyeball the results of the Query and quickly check the data - I can't see that the Patient_IDs are loading properly if I don't know which column is patient_ids.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute SQL from Python: Format the result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504474/execute-sql-from-python-format-the-result-set)

Comment: I personally had better luck with my python/mssql work with pypyodbc, might be worth looking at.  Not exactly what you are looking todo, but might be enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704305/return-column-names-from-pyodbc-execute-statement

Answer (score 2):

It's more than 1 question, I'll try help you and give advice.

1. > I am running a connection to SQL through Python as such, and would like the output to look exactly the same as in SQL.

You are mixing SQL as language and formatted output of some interactive SQL tool.
SQL itself does not have anything about "look" of data.

2. > Also note that neither of the Queries required me to know the column names or widths. My entire method here is attempting to eyeball the results of the Query and quickly check the data - I can't see that the Patient_IDs are loading properly if I don't know which column is patient_ids.

Correct. `cursor.fetchall` returns only data.

Field informations can be read from `cursor.description`.

Read more in [PEP-O249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

3. > how do i get 'data' to appear as a clean table with column names somewhere?

It depends how do you define "appear".

You want: text output, html page or maybe GUI?

- For text output: you can read column names from `cursor.description` and print them before data.
- If you want html/excel/pdf/other - find some library/framework suiting your taste.
- If you want an interactive experience similar to SQL tools - I recommend to look on  `jupyter-notebook` + `pandas`.

Something like:

```
pandas.read_sql_query(sql)
```

will give you "clean table" nothing worse than SQLDeveloper/SSMS/DBeaver/other gives.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution in Spyder environment. In the variable explorer, I can double click the variable name into which i store the data output, and a little tabulated chart comes up like in Microsoft SQL Server or SAS.
Aside from that, I wonder if there is a quick function to juts copy the entire output to the clipboard, while keeping the formatting/delimeters when pasting into EXcel.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need any external libraries.
Refer to this for more details.

[Print results in MySQL format with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865483/print-results-in-mysql-format-with-python)

However, the latest version of MySQL gives an error to this code. So, I modified it.
Below is the query for the dataset

```
stri = "select * from table_name"
cursor.execute(stri) 
data = cursor.fetchall() 
mycon.commit()
```

Below it will print the dataset in tabular form

```
def columnnm(name):
    v = "SELECT LENGTH("+name+") FROM table_name WHERE LENGTH("+name+") = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH("+name+")) FROM table_name) LIMIT 1;"
    cursor.execute(v) 
    data = cursor.fetchall() 
    mycon.commit()
    return data[0][0]

widths = []
columns = []
tavnit = '|'
separator = '+' 
for cd in cursor.description:
    widths.append(max(columnnm(cd[0]), len(cd[0])))
    columns.append(cd[0])

for w in widths:
    tavnit += " %-"+"%ss |" % (w,)
    separator += '-'*w + '--+'

print(separator)
print(tavnit % tuple(columns))
print(separator)
for row in data:
    print(tavnit % row)
print(separator)
```