# How to fetch data from data base in normal form

Tags: python, sql-server

I want to create a mobile app using python and kivy. I have an SQL server and a program which connects to it. However the form of a data which is fetched is not what i need

```
con=db.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                       'Server=dbname'
                       'Database=users;'
                       'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor=con.cursor()
a=self.i.text
print(a)

cursor.execute('SELECT %s FROM users.dbo.users' %a)

res=cursor.fetchall()
print(str(res))


cursor.close()
con.close()
enter code here
```

In output I have : `[(Decimal(9),)]`
How can I make it look like : `9` (Without data type etc)

Comment: Have you trying to show res[0][0] ? I did’t have work with Python but in most programming languages we have too read result as table :).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50862705/9940803

Comment: Other link i think that explain : https://sqlchoice.azurewebsites.net/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/python/windows/step/2.html