# python TypeError not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, regex, sed, fabric

trying to update file with python fabric

```
run('sed -i s/jahil/%s/g /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/%s' % (account))
```

or

```
run('sed -i "s/jahil/%s/g" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/%s' % (account))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Any idea ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Note that `%` is becoming outdated. If you can, update your code to the `.format()` method of string objects.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Actually, while there was talk about getting rid of `%-formatting` when v3 came out, I've since learned that for the time being the `%-formatting` will stick around.

Comment: @Levon: was that mentioned in a PEP? I do know they reintroduced the 'u' in front of Unicode literals to make porting easier.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Take a look at the Note at the bottom of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11099798/1209279, it relates to the Python 3.2 release notes. Until then I also thought `%`-formatting was on its way out in the near future

Comment: @Levon: Thanks, I didn't know that, I thought it would be removed soon. The short conclusion is that `%` is not being removed soon but `.format()` is recommended for new code ( based on http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations )

Comment: @SimeonVisser Agreed, probably a good idea to use the new way for new code. `.format()` has some neat features, I particularly like the `{:,}` which puts commas for readability into larger numbers.

Answer (score 5):

The error is telling you the problem: you have two `%s` placeholders in your string but only one value. I'm assuming you want to use the same value in two places. In which case:

```
run('sed -i s/jahil/%s/g /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/%s' % (account, account))
```

Or, equivalently, using a dictionary so we can use named placeholders:

```
run('sed -i s/jahil/%(a)s/g /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/%(a)s' % {"a": account})
```

It is easy enough to do that kind of string replacement entirely in Python; you might consider doing it that way instead of shelling out.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, there is a mismatch between the number of arguments you say you have and the number you provide. A natural error, since you want them to be the same:

```
run('sed -i "s/jahil/%s/g" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/%s' % (account, account))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have *two* `%s` in your format string, so the string you are building is expecting to get *two* `string` arguments.

Unless `accounts` is a tuple of two strings, you will get this message.

You should have something like this:

```
   % (account, something_else)
```

if both of these strings need to be `account` then  `% (account, account)` will do.