# Dictionary-based string formatting with repeating variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I want to format a string using variables. [I am aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395925/string-formatting-options-pros-and-cons) of the `%` and the `.format()` options.

However, as the string I want to format is a piece of `LaTeX` code, I chose to use the outdated `%`-version since there are already `{` and `}` characters in my code. (And I don't want to escape them because the code will be frequently updated).

My issue is : when I run my code, I get this error :

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

I use a dictionary to define the variables, and they *are all* defined. As far as I understood it, it might come from the `%` character used for comments in `LaTeX` and that could be mis-interpreted in python.

How could I manage this?

Comment: Please isolate the problem so you can show us some code. As it stands, I wonder if you're maybe not using `%(key)s` to get the values from your dict?

Comment: @Ulrich I'll clean up my code and post it. To answer your question, I am using `%(key)s` in my `.tex` code and defined a `dict = {'key1' = "foo", 'key2' = "bar"}`. (-:

Comment: Maybe you've forgotten a `s` somewhere, happens to me all the time, because `%` would give a `KeyError` if it can't find a key from the dict, the `TypeError` you give should only appear if you use the non-dict version and have more `%`s than replacements.

Comment: @Ulrich got it! see my auto-answer. sorry for disturbing, and thx for answer (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem/solution was : my `.tex` code contained following commented `TeX` command : `%\begin{itemize}` and then `%\end{itemize}`.

Python understood the `%\`-pattern as a a call for a key... what wasn't intended.

*Nota:* in order to make your `LaTeX` code `python`-readable, you need to escape your `%`, i.e. **comment your `.tex` code with this pattern : `%%`**  (<kbd>%</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>)