# How to pass on python variables to markdown table?

Tags: python, python-2.7, markdown

My python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from markdown import markdown

fish='salmon'
print fish

s = """
| Type  | Value |
| ------------- | -------------|
| Fish   |  {{fish}} |
"""
html = markdown(s, extensions=['tables'])
print(html)
```

However fish in the table is not replaced with salmon. I tried quotes, single curlies, etc.

Some discussions seem to imply I need to install some more extensions, which I tried randomly.

I guess I am lacking a clean way to resolve this with steps.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Markdown. It's purely a Python string formatting question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String formatting options: pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395925/string-formatting-options-pros-and-cons)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) as so:

```py
hello = "Hey"
world = "Earth"

test = f"""{hello} {world}"""

print(test)
```

outputs:

```
Hey Earth
```

Simply add a `f` before your string, and use curly brackets (`{python-code}`) to insert Python code into the string (in the example above, two variables named `hello` and `world`, respectively).

---

Using your code as an example:

```
from markdown import markdown

fish = "salmon"

s = f"""
| Type  | Value |
| ------------- | -------------|
| Fish   |  {fish} |
"""
html = markdown(s, extensions=["tables"])
print(html)
```

Outputs:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Value</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Fish</td>
<td>salmon</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

---

If you are using Python 2.7, you may use the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function:

```py
from markdown import markdown

fish = "salmon"

s = """
| Type  | Value |
| ------------- | -------------|
| Fish   |  {} |
""".format(fish)

html = markdown(s, extensions=["tables"])
print(html)
```

Comment: I need to use markdown module to create a table and populate the table with the variables. So I guess this is more like a markdown question.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the answer. You may use `f-strings` for your need -- the `{{fish}}` tag you can change it to `{fish}` if you add a `f` to the beginning of the string (`f""" ... text ... """`), and your problem should be taken care of.

Comment: Your code works, per se. However I need to create a table using the **markdown** module. Sorry if I am still missing the point.

Comment: Edited my answer so you can see how it would work with the `markdown` module. The `markdown` module does not specify any manner for which you can pass variables to fill your strings within their [docs](https://python-markdown.github.io/reference/#the-basics) -- that is something you likely have to do pre-`markdown` use.

Comment: I see you pasted the code with the markdown, thank you. It does not work for me, probably because my python version is old (2.7). I am on imac and it comes with the default v2.7. Thank you again!

Comment: Added compatibility for Python 2.7 at the end of the post. Hope it helps!